# sql query work when run it in sqlDeveloper but not work using hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

i have a query that i want to run it using hibernate native sqlQuery

when i run query using sql developer it works fine but when hibernate run it ,it throws this exception

```
.
.
.

 Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
.
.
.
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character
```

here is my sql query:

```
SELECT car_id,car.plate FROM car WHERE car.plate LIKE '%12%' ORDER BY CAR.CAR_ID;
```

please help me ,

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove your semicolon ";".
Cheers.

Comment: thanks,it works ,the problem was ";",but why hibernate throw exception for this wright SQL syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is case sentitive, write your sql statement in lower case. Example:

```
select car_id,car.plate from car car where car.plate like '%12%' order by car.car_id asc;
```

Comment: i used it as native query : Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery(queryString);